# Optimizing performance for max sum in list-of-lists for original list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on my python, doing codewars. The description is as follows:

---

The maximum sum subarray problem consists in finding the maximum sum of a contiguous subsequence in an array or list of integers:

> max_sequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4])
> should be 6: [4, -1, 2, 1]

Easy case is when the list is made up of only positive numbers and the maximum sum is the sum of the whole array. If the list is made up of only negative numbers, return 0 instead.

Empty list is considered to have zero greatest sum. Note that the empty list or array is also a valid sublist/subarray.

---

Great! Done! here's my code, which passes the tests:

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    sums = []
    lists = [[]]
    for i in range(len(arr) + 1):
        for j in range(i):
            lists.append(arr[j: i])
    for i in lists:
        sums.append(sum(i))
    return max(sums)
```

However, for submission, codewars requires you to pass a larger battery of tests, and the tests timeout for larger sets.

In the discussion, many people have the same problem as me. One answer in particular gets to the root of the question, which is what i'm asking here (see the comment below):

> Your code is not optmised to work with longer arrays, whilst your code likely works, it takes too long to solve the harder problems so times out. This questions is as much an optimisation problem as any. So you need to find a way to optimise your solution

That is very true for me! What am i doing "wrong" in this data structure, and how can i improve it? My current guesses for the most expensive computations are:

1. loop within loop (for i in range.... for j in range i)
2. lists.append(arr[j:i])

Any advice? How to improve performance here? I am thinking as much about general data structures and learning as i am about solving this specific question. Thank you!

Comment: Generally one should measure instead of guess where performance bottlenecks are. I only guess that it would be faster to first create an array of partial sums where `ps[i] == sum(arr[:i])`. Then `sum(arr[j:i]) == ps[i] - ps[j]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it.

I completely agree (measure, don't guess). But how would i go about measuring in this case?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't really see the point in such measuring of a cubic time algorithm when it should be solved in linear time...

Comment: Where is the cubic time? This is in quadratic time @KellyBundy

Comment: @merovingian I meant the OP's, not Michael's.

Comment: @KellyBundy In this particular case this may be right but in more complicated and practical cases where e. g. length of "arr" has a known limit, there can exist faster solutions with a theoretically worse time complexity.

Comment: OP's algorithm is in quadratic time. Two nested for loops. Append is in constant time @KellyBundy

Comment: @merovingian But neither slicing nor summing is constant time.

Comment: @merovingian No, creation of slice `arr[j:i]` is a linear copy operation.

Comment: @user11781 One way is to subdivide the function into multiple functions, create the appropriate input dir a subfunction and run it multiple times while measuring it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar idea with earlier post, but it tries to *bail out* earlier when hitting *edge cases*:  (it's still achieved O(n) )

```py
def maxSequence(arr):
    if not arr: return 0              # check if it's empty list
    if max(arr) < 0: return 0         # check if all negatives

    maxx,curr= 0, 0

    for x in arr:
        curr += x
        if curr < 0: 
           curr = 0
        if curr> maxx: 
            maxx = curr
    return maxx
```

Comment: How does it bail out earlier?

Comment: @KellyBundy - first two lines check if it's an *empty array* and all negatives cases.  Hope the notes make it clear now.

Comment: But the other answer does that, too. You make it sound like that's what you differently.

Comment: OK. But I did  stated - *it's the same idea* right?  And the checking on negatives - it's my suggestion?  (he then just updates)...

Comment: It's not just the same idea, it's the exact same.

Answer (score 2):

Reference: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm)

You can use Kadane's Algorithm. The idea is that keep adding elements to `curr` and get the maximum of `curr` and `num`. When the sum of the subarray is positive, it keeps going. When the sum of the subarray is negative, it gives up the negative subarray.

You can consider this example with the following code: `[-1,1000,-2]`. Initially, `curr = -1`. Since it is negative, `curr` gives up `-1` and gets the value of `1000`. Finally, since `1000` is greater than `998`, it returns `1000` as the answer.

This only has a time complexity of O(n) instead of the brute force approach that has an O(n^3).

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    if not arr or max(arr) < 0: 
        return 0

    curr = max_sub = arr[0]

    for num in arr[1:]:
        curr = max(num, curr + num)
        max_sub = max(max_sub, curr)

    return max_sub
```

Comment: This will not pass with an array with all *negative* numbers. Adding this line and it just pass all Test Cases:  ```if max(arr) < 0: return 0```   As the *requirement* spec.

Comment: You are right. The requirement is to return 0 when all elements are negative. Updated. Thank you.

Comment: Now it crashes again for empty input

Comment: Why not just use the normal algorithm?